# MySQL trigger when field change value

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, database-trigger

I have 3 table in database:

1. product

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `product` (
   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `product_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `product_stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. transaction

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
   `transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `transaction_date` datetime NOT NULL,
   `transaction_status` ENUM('pending','process','cancel') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending'
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
3. transaction_details

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `transaction_details` (
   `transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```

if transaction_status in transaction table changed to "cancel" how to update product_stock in product table based on qty in transaction_details table using trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trigger should do what you want. After an `UPDATE` on `transaction` it updates the stock of all products in the transaction (by using `JOIN`s on all three tables to find the relevant products for the transaction):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_stock 
AFTER UPDATE ON transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.transaction_status = 'cancel' THEN
    UPDATE transaction t
    JOIN transaction_details td ON td.transaction_id = NEW.transaction_id
    JOIN product p ON p.product_id = td.product_id
    SET p.product_stock = p.product_stock + td.qty;
  END IF;
END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d50b28067527ff779be179b0484787f4)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm facing mysql error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9